# Rails: possible to restrict a route based on IP address (or range?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sidekiq

I know this usually happens in the controller but I'm wondering if it's possible in `config/routes.rb` to restrict a route based on a specific IP (or range of IPs)? Sort of a whitelist, of sorts.

for example I'd like to restrict this route to only IPs on our subnet:

```
#config/routes.rb
require 'sidekiq/web'

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  ...
  mount Sidekiq::Web, at: "/sidekiq"      # <== restrict this based on IP address
  ...
end
```

Comment: fast & dirty solution would be to add a `before_filter` on the ApplicationController...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the example from the [Rails Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) you could do:

```
#config/routes.rb
require 'sidekiq/web'

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  ...
  mount Sidekiq::Web, at: "/sidekiq", :constraint => Whitelist.new
  ...
end

class Whitelist
  def initialize
    @ips = Whitelist.retrieve_ips
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
  end

  def retrieve_ips
    # get and return your whitelist of ips
  end
end
```

[This post by Yehuda Katz](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-3-makes-life-better) goes into more detail on constraints and how to use them.

Comment: `@ips = Whitelist.retrieve_ips` so `retrieve_ips` is a class method, so `def retrieve_ips` should be `def self.retrieve_ips`